# Running two cables meant for different loads directly from 200Amp electric meter

Tags: electrical-panel

I am building a house in a 3rd world country and have run into a dilemma. We are installing a 200Amp meter and were initially planning to run one 4/0 aluminum cable to the main panel in the house.

Since then we have decided to build a shed, which has its own (smaller) panel that will feed the reserve water tank pump, pool pump, washer/dryer, some exterior lights, the gate and probably more things later.

The electrician was planning to run a 1/0 cable from the house panel to the sub-panel in the bodega. I would prefer to A) not take up any more spaces in the main panel, B) be able to run a decent size load on the shed panel. So I asked him to run another 4/0 aluminum cable (because it appears that's what's required for a 200Amp load) straight from the meter to the panel in the shed. He's saying that connecting 2 4/0 cables inside the meter is impossible because of the terminal size limitation. He's suggesting we run a 2/0 cable for the shed, as anything larger will not fit in the terminal alongside the 4/0 cable.

My question is: assuming the load on the shed panel never exceeds 50Amps as he says (let's say 100 to be on the safe side), **is it safe to run an additional 2/0 aluminum cable on the same lug on the 200Amp meter?** If it is safe to do that, would it be safe to run a 1/0 or thinner cable, as long as it is rated for the load the shed panel will need? Are there double lugs that would accommodate a 4/0 and a 2/0 (or smaller) cables? Would combining the 4/0 cable with the 2/0 cable under one lug be OK? If not with a 2/0 cable, with what size?

Some other information:

In this country a double terminal for the meter is not possible to purchase, and I wouldn't even know what to order on Amazon from the US. But if I could get one, and it allows us to connect 2 4/0 cables at the meter, would this be fine?

Copper is prohibitively expensive here, so running a 2/0 copper cable instead of a 4/0 aluminum cable is pretty much out of the question. Plus we already have the 4/0 cable to run to the house.

All of this is discussed in Spanish, and I'm translating this into English. And I'm not super savvy when it comes to this stuff. So I'm sorry if there are terminology mistakes in this question.

Comment: What make and model is your meter base? Does your utility permit combination *meter main* devices?

Comment: Just found out it's an Eaton 200Amp base with 200Amp breaker. Thought it was just the base. Supposedly it's impossible to buy a meter main with more than one breaker here.

Comment: Can you get us a model number on that meter-main?

Comment: After digging some more (I was just given a picture of the meter base), it is Square D 200A-BP200A, and not Eaton. However, since he hasn't ordered it yet, I am going to see if we can maybe get something like Square D RC816F200CH, which has 8 spaces. Either way, seems like the way to go will be 400Amp to the house and 100Amp to the shed. Whether we have to use the same lugs or put the shed one on one of the breakers remains to be seen. Any idea if those types of breaker mains allow running a 4/0 directly, instead of having to go through the breakers (which have a limit of 100Amp)?

Comment: Can you get us photos of the label on the inside of the meter main?

Comment: This is all I have to go on at the moment - https://capris.cr/square-d-200a-bp200a-combo-base-para-medidor.html There are 3 photos there. Plus I just did some research, and there are no 200Amp meter base combos available in the country at all. Does it even make sense to do the meter base with a 200Amp breaker, instead of just putting in a simple 200Amp meter base and letting the house and shed panels deal with the fuse tripping?

Comment: To clarify, there are no 200Amp meter mains with additional spaces. The only thing available, besides basic meter bases, is something like the product above. It has a lug/breaker part where you attach the cables.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is (essentially) a small but heavy-duty panel **at the meter**. These are often designed as a combination (look for "meter main") so that you can feed a handful of large loads and/or subpanels from the meter - which is *exactly* what you are trying to do. Avoids double-tapping the lugs and provides a safe shutoff for each subpanel separately so that you only need to get the power company involved one time, unless you need to replace the meter main.

Something like [this Eaton CH 200A 8-space](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-CH-200-Amp-8-Space-8-Circuit-EUSERC-Main-Breaker-Meter-Breaker-Ranch-Panel-CMBER88B200BTS/202276013):

[image]

They have some slightly smaller ones, but I wouldn't go smaller than 8 spaces, because each 240V circuit will take 2 spaces. So from a practical standpoint, I would consider it as a panel to feed up to 4 subpanels. But, for example, you might have 2 subpanels (as planned) and use one of the spaces for a convenience circuit or for outdoor lighting.

Comment: Can you recommend a 200Amp (preferably Eaton) meter main with the smallest number of breakers? I will try to see if I can order it. Seems like it's impossible to get something like that here.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with a specific model. Would I be able to run a 4/0 and a 2/0 (or larger) from it?

Comment: Oh, CH not BR I think.

Comment: 4/0, 2/0, etc. will depend on the specific breakers.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the max amperage on a CH breaker. From doing some searching, seems like it's 100Amp. So sounds like this solution does not work for my use case, assuming I want to be able run anything over 100Amps and 1/0 cable. I may still decide that 100Amps and 1/0 is enough, but am I correct in my assumption? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In areas where the NEC has jurisdiction 240.21(B)(5) would allow a 2/0 tap if the lugs were designed for the wires in use, it was outside a building,  protected (by conduit), terminated in a single switch that is located outside or as close to where it enters the building as possible.